# Limit of a function involving sine and cosine

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I need to solve the following limit question

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2+sinx}{4x^2+cosx}$.

I've tried L'hopital rule but it yields that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x+cosx}{8x-sinx}$, what am I going to do with the sine and cos functions as $x$ tends to $\infty$?

Comment: This is an interesting case where L'Hospital does not work. If you apply it  a second time, you get $\dfrac{2-\sin x}{8-\cos x}$, which does not converge. But that does not mean that the initial limit does not exist.

Comment: Hint: with $x=1000$, the ratio is $\dfrac{999999.01519\cdots}{4000000.17364\cdots}=0.24999\cdots$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a different approach:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^2+\sin x}{4x^2+\cos x}= \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1+\frac{\sin x}{x^2}}{4+\frac{\cos x}{x^2}}=\frac14$$

As a practice, work on the limit that you obtained using L'hopital rule as well using a similar approach.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Divide both numerator and denominator by $x$ in the final limit you obtained.

Comment: Thank you for the hint.